# Could I have an explanation of the syntax of this javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, syntax, closures

I recently had a question answered that has, for me, raised syntax questions. I have looked at explanations of closures on SO but the answers do not address my specific questions below. I have tried discussing this with the person who provided me with the answer and they suggested I ask another question. Here is the solution I was offered, which works, but which I do not understand:

```
for (var loop = 0;loop<onHoverSections.length;loop++) {
    var extractedID = onHoverSections[loop].onHover;
    for (var loopInner = 0;loopInner<sections.length;loopInner++) {
        if (sections[loopInner].ID==extractedID) {
            ( function(p_loop, p_loopInner) {
                onHoverSections[p_loop].hover(
                    function() {
                        sections[p_loopInner].trigger('onHover');
                    },
                    function() {
                        //
                    }
                );
            }
            (loop, loopInner) );
        }
    }
}
```

My questions relate to this section of code:

```
( function(p_loop, p_loopInner) {
    // .. code removed
}
(loop, loopInner) );
```

My questions are:
Why are the 'loop' and 'loopInner' parameters in a set of brackets AFTER the function definition?
If they are parameters of a different function, where is the function definition?
Why does this function not work when the outer brackets are removed?

I would like to understand this syntax well enough so I can replicate this code in other cases and understand WHY it works. Thanks.

Comment: It's called a "self evoking function". The function is defined, and called with arguments `loop` and `loopInner`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different names for them - Self executing function, Self invoking function or  Immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

Basically it is a function that is created and executed immediately.

In the code above the function is

1. created to take two parameters, called `p_loop` and `p_loopInner` within the function.
2. Immediately invoked and passed two parameters - `loop` and `loopInner`

The purpose of this is to preserve the values of the loop indeces, so that the correct values are accessible within the inner scope.

Explained in detail [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: I see. It seems the answer-er of my previous question was actually introducing me to TWO new concepts, not just one. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: These are used a lot to preserve values when new scope is created. Have a look at the module pattern which is where I learnt a lot about JavaScript scope and also makes use of an IIFE - This is a great reference - http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 2):

It's an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Perhaps it would help you to see what's happening by moving the parenthesis:

```
(function(p_loop, p_loopInner) {
    // .. code removed
})(loop, loopInner);
```

As we can see, the first expression returns an anonymous function that takes `p_loop` and `p_loopInner` parameters. Then with `(loop, loopInner);` we invoke it just like any other function.